# can we reduce spaces between table headers in hive or can we turnoff tablename in header

Tags: database, hive

I am using hive in terminal, I want to enable header name of tables. Did that using "**set hive.cli.print.header=true;**"
but the problems is the space between column headers in the results of a hive query are not aligned.
Is there any option to reduce the spaces between the header.
or alternatively can we change the header format from **table_name.column_name** to **column_name** only.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to remove the column header format from table_name.column_name to column_name.

You can do this by setting the below property in the same Hive session before running the query,

`set hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names=false;`

This way, the unique column names will be set to false and you will see only the column names instead of table names along with it.

Hope it helps!